# Intarray is available but can't seem to be able to use the icount function

Tags: postgresql-10

My question is below. Following the suggestion from one of the comments, I started to search for search_path and extensions. I came on to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986368/installing-postgresql-extension-to-all-schemas. The answer by a_horse_with_no_name worked brilliantly! Thank you!! (And, thank you to Krismorte for the edits making the post much more readable).

---

I am running PostgreSQL 10.

I ran the following command to set it up:

```
sudo su - postgres -c psql template1 <<OMG
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
DROP USER IF EXISTS "ec2-user";
CREATE USER "ec2-user" WITH PASSWORD '*******';
ALTER USER "ec2-user" CREATEDB;
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
OMG
```

I then created another DB, `sent_4_snps` using the ec2-user. This was done within a Python script using the following code:

```
sys.stdout.write('The SNPdb {0} does not exist - running sql to create database\n'.format(self.snpdb_name))
make_db_conn_string = 'host=\'{0}\' dbname=postgres user=\'{1}\' password=\'{2}\''.format(self.pg_host,
                                                                              self.pg_uname, self.pg_pword)
conn = psycopg2.connect(make_db_conn_string)
conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE {0}'.format(self.snpdb_name))
cur.close()
conn_string = 'host=\'{0}\' dbname={1} user=\'{2}\' password=\'{3}\''.format(self.pg_host, self.snpdb_name,
                                                                             self.pg_uname, self.pg_pword)
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cur = conn.cursor()
sql_script = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'template_snapperdb_denovo_refs_sql')
cur.execute(open(sql_script, 'r').read())
```

This essentially runs the CREATE DATABASE command as the ec2-user.

The DB has the following table:

Table "public.strains_snps"

```
   Column    |       Type        | 
-------------+-------------------+
 name        | character varying |
 variants_id | integer[]         |
 ignored_pos | integer[]         |
 id          | integer           |
```

If I try to run the following query:

```
select variants_id, name, icount(variants_id) as count 
from strains_snps;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  function icount(integer[]) does not exist LINE 1: select
>   variants_id, name, icount(variants_id) as count from ...
>                                     ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type
>   casts.

I have tried re-running the command to add the extension, but I just get a message saying that the extension has already been created. I have searched everywhere, and I can't seem to find any other information. I have tried using \df on the psql to search for the icount function, but it doesn't find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the exact database creation command you use?  What is your search_path set to?  try `\df *.icount`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the response. The full DB creation command is here: https://github.com/phe-bioinformatics/snapperdb/blob/master/snapperdb/snpdb/template_snapperdb_denovo_refs_sql

It is invoked via a Python script.

I am a bit new to postgres, and was unfamiliar with the search_path. Mine shows the following:

sent_4_snps=> show search_path;
   search_path
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)

I tried \df *.icount, the result was empty.

Thank you, again.

I suspect now that the search_path might be missing something.

Comment: Your github script is presumably the thing you are running in template1 to populate the database.  But how does `sent_4_snps` get created?  That is the database creation command I am looking for.

Comment: @jjanes it was created within Python. I'll update the post above to include the code. But, I think I ran into the problem because I ran the SQL commands in the GitHub script as a user without superuser privileges?

Comment: And, the command does not seem to be inheriting from template1. Humm...

Answer (score 1):

I found that `intarray` stuff doesn't work if you don't have schema `public` in your `search_path`.  Vis:

```
mydb=# show search_path;
 search_path
-------------
 public
(1 row)

mydb=# select icount(array[1,2,3]);
 icount
--------
      3
(1 row)

mydb=# set search_path to '';
SET
mydb=# show search_path;
 search_path
-------------
 ""
(1 row)

mydb=# select icount(array[1,2,3]);
ERROR:  42883: function icount(integer[]) does not exist
LINE 1: select icount(array[1,2,3]);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
LOCATION:  ParseFuncOrColumn, parse_func.c:627
```

This is even true of operators:

```
mydb=# set search_path to public;
SET
mydb=# select array[1,2,3] - array[2,3];
 ?column?
----------
 {1}
(1 row)

mydb=# set search_path to '';
SET
mydb=# select array[1,2,3] - array[2,3];
ERROR:  42883: operator does not exist: integer[] - integer[]
LINE 1: select array[1,2,3] - array[2,3];
                            ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
LOCATION:  op_error, parse_oper.c:731
```